# How to play audio by iterating in python without pauses?

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing

I'm working on a piece of code the outputs audio as new data comes in.

Basically,

```
y = # song array
sr = # sample

# assume sub_array are subsets of y of equal length. 
for sub_array in y:
  play(sub_array)
```

When I do this, each iteration has a slight pause. How do I get rid of that pause?

Comment: Check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66337957/12750353), in your case you are not writing to disk but is probably playing synchronously. You have to play asynchronously with some buffer.

Comment: Using a Stream object instead of a simple play() function solved the unit case. I still don't fully understand callback functions, but this helped a lot. Thanks Bob!